# Does Linux provide a method to fix a thread to a P-core or E-core?

Tags: intel, multithreading

On chips 12th gen and newer in the Intel lineup, (and I'm told on ARM chips) there are distinct classes of cores with different clock speeds

- P-cores for performance, higher clock speed
- E-cores for energy efficiency, lower clock speed

This is different from the chips that I understand where the frequency can be throttled but it's the same across cores.

Is there a method to bind a thread to the class of P-cores or E-cores?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread

Comment: @Artem I don’t think the question is “how can I set the affinity of a specific thread”, but rather “how can I set the affinity to P-cores or E-cores”, *i.e.* by type rather than number.

Comment: @StephenKitt exactly.

Comment: I don't think there's such a feature in the linux kernel but going by numbers first go real P cores, then go P-cores HT siblings, then go E cores. You can bind threads to the range of P cores or E cores.

Comment: @Artem that depends on the system firmware, there’s no hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: I've not seen a different division for cores for ADL/RPL systems. I thought this question is specifically about the last two gens of Intel CPUs. `lstopo` from the `hwloc` package will tell you everything.